# Mount network folder in Vista Home Premium

Tags: windows, networking, windows-vista, mount

I need to mount network public folder(s) on logon in Windows Vista Home Premium under specific letter. Is this possible in Vista HP and how?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from a command prompt net use z: \\server\path\to\drive where you replace z with the letter you want.  There are also options for passing a username and password although I don't remember what they are right now net use /help should get them for you.

Comment: To make it connect at logon, you need to add a "-p" to the end of that statement to make it persistent.

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer a graphical way of doing this, navigate to the "My Computer". There should be an option to mount a network drive. This will pop a wizard allowing you to mount the drive. If you don't see the option, try hitting the alt key, which pops down the (otherwise hidden) menu. It should be under Tools.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on My Computer and choose Map Network Drive. Pick the drive letter that you want to use and the path to the share. Make sure the Reconnect at logon is checked so that it stays persistent though a reboot.